# Why is TeXnicCenter incorrectly loading my template files?

Tags: texniccenter

In my template .tex file (encoded as UTF-8), if I open it in TeXnicCenter, it displays correctly, and last line of the document is

(line 136) `\end{document}`

as one would expect from a .tex file. Opening the .tex file using a regular text editor also yields the same correct document. However, if I actually use File -> New -> File from Template and select my template, the opened document displays the following last lines:

(line 136) `\end{document`

(line 137) `NUL`

(line 138) `NUL`

Not only are there two new lines (with Null characters) formed when I create a new file from template, but the curly brace to close the .tex document is missing! What is going on here? I currently have to manually add the curly brace and delete the null characters every time I want to use my template.

EDIT: I should mention that I am using TeXnicCenter 2.0 Beta 1. I know, I know, I should update, but I would like to know whether this is a fundamental bug with my version or whether it is something I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Could you double-check the encoding of your file? I personally like Notepad++ for checking and converting the file encoding, which tool did you use for creating the template?

Comment: And yes, you should update: If that behaviour is gone after the update then you know that it was a bug and nothing you were doing wrong... ;-)

Comment: Yes, I opened it in Notepad++ and it is in UTF-8. I'm only hesitant to update because it has happened in the past that some of my TeXnicCenter configurations were lost because they changed the program in a significant way, and it took some effort to reconfigure. But yes, I will update shortly unless somebody here identifies a problem on my end.

Comment: This sound very much like your problem: http://sourceforge.net/p/texniccenter/bugs/286/ But they say it was closed long time ago.

Comment: Thank you. I believe that is the definitive answer I need: so it is a bug with TeXnicCenter itself. I do think it is interesting that the bug was reported in 1.0, while I am using a relatively recent version. Nevertheless, time to update!

Comment: @ChristopherA.Wong: JFYI No problem here with TXC 2.02 stable. I just imported intentionally the `Brief.tex` attached in the linked bug tracker entry above and everything went fine.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a bug in a beta version of TeXnicCenter, which was fixed at least with the latest stable version.

Comment: @Speravir, yes, I could not confirm that my question was actually caused by a bug until now. I accept that the question is off-topic now.

Comment: The linked bug was in version 1, which was released years before any version 2 beta. So before closing this question I would recommend further testing. Especially it would be interesting to see if updating fixes this issue. If not, the linked bug should be reopened.